# Treeview of a Dictionary and binding checkbox to every node wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, treeview

I have a dictionary with list of values associated with one key. The key makes the parent node and values of list makes the child node.

The dictionary is of type

```
   Dictionary<string,List<string>>
```

I have a populated dictionary hierarchyList of the same type. Here is the code i tried but it doesn't work .

```
   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding hierarchyList}" >
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Values}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    </TreeView>
```

And also i need checkbox binded with each node. How do i go about that?

Comment: To what should this `CheckBox`be bound to? I don't see `bool` property.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update your bindings like below:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding hierarchyList}" >
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    </TreeView>
```